# SQL multiple tables query for column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have multiple tables (number > 100) within a database in SQL, each table may have a few hundred entries.

For every table, I am seeking to retrieve simply the names of the columns from the tables which have at least 1 non-null entry.

How can I do this?

Comment: See normalisation.

Comment: Are you looking for `not null` columns or nullable columns that have `is not null` data?

Answer (score 0):

To return table/column name:

```
 SELECT table_name, column_name
 FROM information_schema.columns
```

That's pretty easy, here's a solution for nulls depending on if you have permissions:

```
select a.table_name
    , schema_name
    , sum(c.rows) total_rows
from
    information_schema.tables  a
    join information_schema.schemas b on (a.schema_id = b.schema_id)
    join information_schema.partitions c on (a.object_id = c.object_id)
where c.index_id in (0,1)
group by a.name,b.name
having sum(c.rows) = 0;
```

Note: I did this in vertica, and you have to have access to partitions.  Also, some dbs use sys instead of information_schema, but the idea is the same.